Torque applying on both rotating and non-rotating object

In rod reference frame:

origin is center of the rod,
pitching axis is coinciding with the rod
external torque is applied in rolling axis

If a torque is applied to non-rotating object(the rod and the spheres), always in the same  magnitude and a wheel is rotating always(not sliding to the right or the left)at the center of the rod connecting spheres as shown on the picture,
assuming:

the wheel rotates around the rod which is coinciding with angular velocity vector of the wheel, bearings are frictionless

this experiment is realized in a vacuumed gravity-free place

rod mass is ignored, and for simplicity you can assume sphere mass is a point mass with some value



how will torque be shared between the wheel and spheres?

as a result of torque applied to the wheel, in addition to rotation around rolling axis, the wheel will try to rotate around
yawing axis  due to gyroscopic effect but it will also try to rotate spheres, what will be result of this fact?


If you explain behavior of this object based on reference frames i would be pleased.

Please, add some details: is there an hinge between the wheel and the rod connecting the two masses? Is this system constrained to the ground? If not, could we assume that weight is negligible?

The rod makes a torque to the wheel as it attempts to move obliquely, but I am not sure if that is what you are asking

Try expressing every state variable as a function of angular momentum.

So basically the entire thing will rotate clockwise as seen from above, and the wheel will keep spinning along the rod axis

I meant about, not along

@Pato Galmarini  why, you said 'The rod makes a torque to the wheel' above, if so there is some torque acting on the spinning wheel therefore it must be subjected gyroscopic effect

but it is a gyroscopic effect, the torque is the same, but if the wheel were not rotating, the change in angular momentum would make the device to rotate vertically, instead of precising horizontally.

an intuitive analogy is a central force made by a rope. if a ball at the end of the rope is moving tangentially to the rope, pushing the rope towards the center makes it move in a circle, if it starts at rest it makes it move towards the center.

Can you please rewrite this question, stating rotation around the x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis in terms of rolling, pitching, and swiveling. The first two are borrowed from aviation. (Aviation uses yaw for the third one, I replaced that with swivel.) For instance : you write "it will also try to rotate spheres" For the purpose of making sure there is no ambiguity: I recommend to always specify which axis of rotation you have in mind. In the diagram you provided it could be either pitching or swiveling
